# pandas apply upper() works on each of two string columns separately, but not together

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a simple dataframe along these lines:

```
    a       b
 0  horse  cat
 1  dog    elephant
```

running:

```
df.loc[:,'a'].apply(lambda x: x.upper())
```

or

```
df.loc[:,'b'].apply(lambda x: x.upper())
```

gets the animals in the respective column capitalized. However, running

```
df.loc[:,'a':'b'].apply(lambda x: x.upper())
```

or

```
df.loc[:,['a','b']].apply(lambda x: x.upper())
```

results in "AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'upper'", 'occurred at index a')".

Obviously, I would like to know how to fix it (i.e., be able to uppercase both columns at once). But I would also like to know how a column can have the attribute 'upper' on its own, but lose it when the lambda is applied to it as part of multiple columns.

Comment: You are look at the difference in using`pd.DataFrame.apply` and `pd.Series.apply`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use str accessor:

```
df.loc[:,'a':'b'].apply(lambda x: x.str.upper())
```

OUtput:

```
       a         b
0  HORSE       CAT
1    DOG  ELEPHANT
```

## What is going on here?

Okay Let's do a litte debugging:

```
def f(x):
    print(type(x))
    print(type(x[0]))

df.loc[:,'a':'b'].apply(f)
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'str'>
```

Here we are using `pd.DataFrame.apply`.

A pandas Series is passed to the function f in this case, therefore we can use the .str accessor to call string function upper.

Now, let's look at the first case:

```
def f(x):
    print(type(x))
    print(type(x[0]))

df.loc[:,'a'].apply(f)
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Here, were are using `pd.Series.apply` and pass each value itself.  Therefore, we can simply call string function upper directly on each value.

And, you can use also `pd.DataFrame.applymap` as [@chrisz shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631514/6361531) in his solution to pass every cell value of the dataframe to the function.

Comment: Yup, live and learn! I now know not just how to fix it, but why there was a problem to begin with. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use [**`applymap`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) in order to:

> Apply a function to a DataFrame that is intended to operate elementwise, i.e. like doing map(func, series) for each series in the DataFrame

```
df[['a', 'b']].applymap(lambda x: x.upper())

       a         b
0  HORSE       CAT
1    DOG  ELEPHANT
```

Comment: Happy to help, I would recommend checking out Scott's explanation of why your initial attempt wasn't working, it covers all the good stuff.